# How to use same config file for serving modules with requirejs and using r.js on the server side to concatenate and minify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am working on a project that uses requirejs to dynamically load modules from a web browser. Some of the modules are vendor files, e.g. jQuery, which are all installed into a folder `/project/root/lib/` via bower. This project's modules are located in a folder `/project/root/components/`. So I have a requirejs config, `components/main.js`, that looks something like this:

```
  requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/components',
    paths: {
      jquery: '/lib/jquery/jquery',
    }
  });
```

This way, when a vendor module is requested, require finds it by using the mappings defined in `paths`, while all other modules are located relative to `components`.

I also want to use r.js to perform concatenation and minification and reduce all javascript files to simply `app.js` for use in production. I was able to successfully perform this task with `r.js -o build.js`. Here is what `build.js` looks like:

```
({
    baseUrl:'components',
    out:    'js/app.js',
    name:   'app',
    paths: {
      jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery'
    }
})
```

However, because there are dozens of vendor file paths defined in my require.js config (`main.js`), I don't want to have to replicate the configuration across two different files. I would rather use a single config file. The problem is that the paths defined in `main.js` are absolute (`/lib/...`, `/components`), because they're URL paths, but the paths in `build.js` need to be relative (`../lib/...`, `./components`), because they're filesystem paths. Is there a way to reconcile these differences and define the paths only in `main.js`, which I then I load in using `mainConfigFile` in `build.js`? I tried using the require config called `map` in `build.js`, but this method required that I defined a new mapping for each module, which is just as bad as re-defining all of the paths. I want a blanket mapping, essentially.

Is there a method to consolidate my config files to avoid duplicate path definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that requires using absolute paths in the configuration passed to RequireJS. RequireJS interprets paths that are relative using `baseUrl` as the starting point so this should work:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/components',
    paths: {
      jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery',
    }
});
```

RequireJS will perform the final path computation for `jquery` by merging `/components` with `../lib/jquery/jquery`, which resolves to `/lib/jquery/jquery`, which is exactly the same as the absolute path that was there originally.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. However, it required going through all the files that already had `require` and `define` statements and updating them to work with the new config. It's kind of a PITA trying to keep three different requirejs configs in sync - this project currently has one for the karma test runner, one for the node server, and one for the r.js optimizer.

Comment: Why did you have to change your ``require`` and ``define`` calls? Take jquery, for instance. With the original configuration, you would have listed it as ``"jquery"`` in the dependencies, and after changing its path, you still list it as ``"jquery"``. Is there something I missed in the question?

Comment: I had to change the calls to modules defined in the project which are located in `/components`.